# Monte Carlo test of Space-Time clustering in R

Tags: r, clustering

I have several point patterns representing the distribution of territories of a bird species. Each point pattern represents the distribution of one year. I already succeeded in computing Ripley's L function for each year seperately, but now I would like to test whether there is space-time clustering present over all years.

Some research leads me to a Monte-Carlo test of space-time clustering which should be possible with the R-package SPLANCS. 
I did not manage to find some examples on this (with R-scripts) and the manuals (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splancs/splancs.pdf) are too advanced for me. Is there anyone who can provide an example, or can explain how exactly my data should look like before I read them in in R?

I assume that my points for all years should be put together in one shapefile. But how do I link that with a 'vector of times'. And most of all, what does a vector of times looks like?

Comment: That should all be explained in the help(stkhat) documentation of splancs... Will write a full answer later if you cant work it out.